# WebDriver Selenium: Javascript code coverage without server access

Tags: javascript, selenium, webdriver, code-coverage

Are there any tools that will allow me to measure the javascript code coverage of the website I'm testing with Webdriver when I don't have access to the server-side?

For example, I have no server access to stackoverflow.com. If I program Selenium WebDriver to click on javascript controlled elements on this site, is there a way for me to measure the amount of code coverage of the javascript that were loaded on my browser for this site?

A popular tool seems to be JsCover and JsCoverage, but they seem to only work if you have server access. http://siliconforks.com/jscoverage/faq.html

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I have heard of [ScriptCover](https://code.google.com/p/script-cover/wiki/ScriptCoverDesign), never used it thou